# Finding minimum number of squares inside a rectangle

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I have this question where I have to find the minimum number of squares (of the same dimensions) inside of a rectangle. I found that this problem has a solution where I can calculate the **LCM** and the **HCF** of the given sides of the rectangle and by finally **dividing** the **LCM** by the **HCF**... I get the correct answer!
I want to know why this logic works? Can someone explain it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Suppose you have a $3\times4$ rectangle. Then you cannot fit any squares side $4$ inside it, you can fit 1 square side 3. Do you mean the squares have to *tile* the rectangle?

Comment: Yes... Sorry I didn't write the question properly... I mean if there is a rectangle **6 x 4**. I want to _**tile**_ squares inside it, but they should be minimum in number. For example, if I try to _**tile**_ squares **1 x 1** then those would be the maximum no. of squares I could _**tile**_... I want the minimum number, so in the case of **6 x 4** rectangle, I can have **six 2 x 2** squares. I cannot decrease the number **6** any further because I want to fit squares of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest square that can tile a rectangle with sides $a,b$ has side $\gcd(a,b)$. The number of squares you will then use is

$$\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\cdot\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)} = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2} = \frac{\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$$

because $ab=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\cdot\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You clarification was short and perfect!